# How do I stub part of my session to simulate an authorized session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stub

I have a before filter on my Products Controller:

```
before_filter :authorize, only: [:create, :edit, :update]
```

my `authorize` method is defined in my `application_controller` as:

```
def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not authorized" if current_user.nil?
end
```

and current_user is defined as:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

**In my rspec, I am trying:**

```
before(:each) do
    session.stub!(:user_id).and_return("admin@email.com")
end
```

But I am still getting an error as follows:

```
ProductsController PUT update with valid params redirects to the product
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(product)
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/products/1> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/login>
```

. . . which means that my test is not logged in at the time of the request.

What am I missing here?

Is there a better way to approach this situation?

Comment: `user_id` is not a method on `session` that you can stub, `session` is a hash with `user_id` as one of its keys.  In your `before` block, what happens if you do a `session[:user_id] = "admin@email.com"` instead?

Comment: I had tried that and it gave me similar issues (I couldn't stub it that way).  I think most of the issue here was my lack of clear-thinking at the time.  Stuartc's answer below was a good solution.  Thanks for the assistance though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering you are testing the controller, and trying to keep it focussed on the controller you could stub the `current_user` method with a real user or a mock.

```
before(:each) do
   ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user = mock('user'))
end
```

With that you will have access to the `user` mock to apply further expectations and stubs if needed.
If the mock gets in the way, change it out for a real `User` object.

Comment: You know those times when you spend more than 2 hours flirting with the right answer and your brain just can't get it?  This was one of those times for me -- really appreciate the clarification.

Comment: It's a pleasure, glad I could help!